# Rails 3 loads mailer fixtures. How do I stop this from happening?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, testing, fixtures, mailer

I assumed it was a Rails convention that mailer fixtures reside in a folder named after that mailers class name, and inside that folder are fixtures named after each action in the mailer class.

But when I run my unit tests, I notice rails raises and error because it tries to drop a test table names after the mailer class and mailer action class put together... this is odd, I would have assumed rails would know better and ignore these fixtures that are simply used for mailer content formatting comparison.

Rails 3 documentation on the mailer fixtures:

> 10.2.1 Revenge of the Fixtures
>
> For the purposes of unit testing a mailer, fixtures are used to
> provide an example of how the output should look. Because these are
> example emails, and not Active Record data like the other fixtures,
> they are kept in their own subdirectory apart from the other fixtures.
> The name of the directory within test/fixtures directly corresponds to
> the name of the mailer. So, for a mailer named UserMailer, the
> fixtures should reside in test/fixtures/user_mailer directory.

#### I'm using rails 3.0.12

test helper contents:

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test"
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
    fixtures :all
    # Add more helper methods to be used by all tests here...
end
```

my fixtures directory layout:

```
test/fixtures/card_sender_mailer/card_update_notificaiton.yml
```

This is the error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Table 'monkey_test.card_sender_mailer_card_update_notification' doesn't exist: DELETE FROM `card_sender_mailer_card_update_notification`
```

I assume that because I'm loading all fixtures it's trying to load this as well, so how do I load all fixtures except the mailer fixtures?

#### Update 1

When I try loading the fixtures with rake in the terminal, I get a similar error:

```
Tasks: TOP => db:fixtures:load
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
/Users/victorstan/Sites/ContactMonkey ∴ bundle exec rake db:fixtures:load 
rake aborted!
Mysql2::Error: Table 'monkey_development.card_sender_mailer_card_update_notification' doesn't exist: DELETE FROM `card_sender_mailer_card_update_notification
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I will answer my own question, despite the Rails documentation: mailer fixtures should be .txt files not .yml files, if you don't want them loaded into the DB. Maybe I'll contribute to the documentation one day.

Comment: I would up vote this 50 times if I could.  It's 2016...and the docs STILL don't point out that mailer fixtures are .txt files.

Answer (score 0):

I moved all subfolders to test/files